# unable to read/write CIFS mounts in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I upgraded my laptop from 11.04 too 11.10 and since then the CIFS mounts are not working.

Before the upgrade it would allow mounts on host names, in 11.10 it's only IP addresses (not much of an issue), however all the shares I mount are as read-only despite the `fstab` file declaring the options `rw` and `auto`. I have `chown`ed the mount point to be `nogroup.nouser` and it still wont work, here is an extract from my `fstab`:

```
//192.168.1.1/stories /home/paul/Documents/Stories cifs rw,user,exec,auto,username=<user>,password=<password> 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try mounting share with `noperm` option, e.g. your `/etc/fstab` line should be:

```
//192.168.1.1/stories /home/paul/Documents/Stories cifs rw,user,exec,auto,**noperm**,username=,password= 0 0
```

It is useful when client and host uids/gids differs (see 'man smbmount')

Answer (score 3):

Try with this one. It worked for me:

```
//192.168.1.1/stories /home/paul/Documents/Stories cifs iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,username=,password= 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ShareScanner which is almost similar to netscan of windows. It supports nautilus, dolphin and konqueror.You can mount network shares with a mere click. You can download it from:

http://sharescanner.net84.net